# Is there a way to specify which string comparison to use on a site-wide level?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The reason I ask is because I just found a really weird bug that only happened on our production box. Here is a small example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var form = Request.Form;
    string name = form.GetValueOrDefaultIfKeyExists("firstName");
    string email = form.GetValueOrDefaultIfKeyExists("emailAddress");
    ... 
}
```

On our production box - name and email would be String.Empty after this code ran - even though the form contained keys with 'firstName' and 'emailAddress'. The `GetValueOrDefaultIfKeyExists` is a custom extension method, implemented this way:

```
public static Boolean HasKey(this NameValueCollection collection, String key)
{
    return collection.AllKeys.Any(x => x.Equals(key));
}

public static String GetValueOrDefaultIfKeyExists(this NameValueCollection collection, String key)
{
    return GetValueOrDefaultIfKeyExists(collection, key, String.Empty);
}

public static String GetValueOrDefaultIfKeyExists(this NameValueCollection collection, String key, String defaultValue)
{
    return collection.HasKey(key) ? collection[key].Trim() : defaultValue;
}
```

The problem was with the `HasKey()` method on our production box. This returned false on our production box until i changed it to this implementation:

```
public static Boolean HasKey(this NameValueCollection collection, String key)
{
    return collection.AllKeys.Any(x => x.Equals(key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

Does anyone have a possible explanation for the difference in behavior? Both the dev and production boxes are using IIS6.0 and asp.net v2.0. I'm not really sure what else to look at here...

edit: when i run the page on localhost and dump the variables to the page by just looping over the Request.Form key/values, i get output like this:

```
__VIEWSTATE = /wEPDwUJNTE2ODkwODQ2ZGS2XnJpbO5ngrJFByrGtuNn3PkU5A==

LandingPage = ~/Newsletter/thank-you.aspx

SourceDesc = 676

emailAddress = bntest222@test.com

confirmEmailAddress = bntest222@test.com

firstName = mtest

postalCode = 23320
```

the same code run on our production box dumps this:

```
__viewstate = /wEPDwUJNTE2ODkwODQ2ZGSWeuNU+/5eQHvpsMc66Ayh4lEdWQ==

confirmemailaddress = mtest332@test.com

emailaddress = mtest332@test.com

firstname = mtest

landingpage = ~/Newsletter/thank-you.aspx

postalcode = 23320
```

it looks like the keys are being lower-cased... why?

Comment: are the keys in fact the same casing from dev to prod?

Comment: they were lowercase'd when i dumped them to the page in production... any idea why?

Comment: well if you changed the casing when moving to production that's the problem

Comment: is there a setting you know of that may affect this? the code on the dev/production boxes are exactly the same. i'm thinking this may be some global setting i'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't *precisely* answer your question, but: FxCop/Code Analysis will warn you about about any code in your project which doesn't specify an explicit `StringComparison` or format provider, but should.